# Extracting custom attributes in an XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema

I am able to get all the nodes using the `System.Xml.Schema` class, but I an not able to query the **b:fieldInfo** node and extract the attributes using any standard xml methods.  I don't want to parse it as a string.

```
 <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Line1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0"/>
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Start" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="15" sequence_number="1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy with `XDocument`

```
var snip = XDocument.Parse(feildInfo);
var value = snip.Root.Attribute("justification").Value;
```